# Discord bot, como hacer que mi bot solo lea de un canal dado mediante el codigo

Tags: python, discord.py, bot

tengo programado en python un bot para discord, y quiero hacer que desde mi código de alguna manera se le asigne al bot para que solo pueda leer de un canal, porque el problema que tengo es que esta todo el rato leyendo de todos los canales y eso causa conflictos. He probado a hacerlo con Roles en discord pero no me parece buena idea, quiero caparlo desde el código de alguna manera.

```
#CLASE PRINCIPAL DEL BOT

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self): #Enciende el bot
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message): 
        
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!call'):
            print("\n********* El usuario "+ str(message.author) + " esta usando el bot *********")
           
            try:
                
                await message.channel.send('1. Indica un canal')
                chanelName = await self.wait_for('message', check=None, timeout=60.0)
                await message.channel.send(chanelName)
               
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                return await message.channel.send('Has tardado mucho en introducir datos, a MIMIR!!!')
        
        elif  message.content.startswith('!help'):
             
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Help",description="1. Indica un canal \n2. Indica el título de la colección \n3. Indica el precio \n4. Indica una fecha (timestamp) \n5. Indica el supply \n6. Indica la información \n7. Indica el riesgo (0-10) \n8. Indica su web \n9. Indica su twitter (usuario) \n10. Indica su discord \n11. Indica su marketplace \n \n Se tiene 30s entre cada campo para introducir los datos, sino el bot se reinicia",timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=242424)        
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Dos cosas. Primero, podés checkear el canal del que proviene el mensaje (message.channel.id es tan solo el id que Discord le asignó al canal, puedes hacer message.channel.id == el id del canal). No vas a dejar de recibir mensajes de ese canal, pero al menos podrás filtrarlos dentro del código. Segundo, por que te matas creando tu propio código para procesar comandos cuando tenés [discord.ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html)?

Comment: @DanteS. Lo primero lo probe pero se me colaban algunos mensajes nose porqué,  aun así lo volvere a intentar de esa forma, y lo segundo que comentas si estoy usando esa librería  de discord.ext.commands, lo que pasa es que en el código no se ve porque he quitado líneas, tengo que crear código a partir de discord.py porque los comandos que quiero tener no existen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He hecho una función que devuelve true siempre que el id del canal extraído del ctx es igual a un ID pasado en concreto y además de la persona que ejecuta del mensaje que yo quiero, y si es falso, no ejecuta el bot.

```
async def leerMensaje(self,autorDeLaCall): #Lee solo del canal chanelIDdiscord, y devuelve el mensaje leido en newMessage
    chanelIDdiscordAux=0
    idChanelNewMessage=-1
    tiempoTranscurrido=0
    tiempoRestante=0
    personaIDnew=-1

    while idChanelNewMessage!=chanelIDdiscordAux or autorDeLaCall!=personaIDnew: # Asi controlo que el mensaje que se lea sea solo del canal que queremos (chanelIDdiscord) y de la persona que inicia !call            
        inicio = time.time() 
        newMessage = await self.wait_for('message', check=None, timeout=180.0-tiempoRestante) #Para que si se manda un mensaje de otro canal, cuando se vuelva al bucle al usuario del canal que esperamos realmente el mensaje le quede el tiempo que le quedaba al principio, ya que sin hacer esto de tiempo trasncurrido le resetearia el tiempo y le volveria quedar 60
        idChanelNewMessage= newMessage.channel.id
        personaIDnew=newMessage.author.id
        chanelIDdiscordAux=chanelIDdiscord
        fin = time.time()
        tiempoTranscurrido=fin-inicio
        tiempoRestante=tiempoRestante+tiempoTranscurrido
        # print("dentro")
        # print(tiempoAux)
        

    return newMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes filtar los canales de los que quieres leer el mensaje de esta forma.

```
async def on_message(self, message): 
    if message.author.id == self.user.id or message.channel.id != LA ID DEL CANAL:
        return

    resto del código....
```

Te recomiendo que si vas a crear comandos por texto, los hagas a través de la extensión de discord.py `discord.ext.commands`. En vez de crear un discord.Client, puedes crear un commands.Bot.
Además, esto te permitirá utilizar [Checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=checks#checks) para filtrar los canales en los que quieres que se puedan utilizar.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, lo de los checks es muy útil y no sabia que estaban